# Naming a variable from a text file

Tags: c#, string, variables, naming

I'm making a program in C# that uses mathematical sets of numbers. I've defined the class Conjunto (which means "set" in spanish). Conjunto has an ArrayList that contains all the numbers of the set. It also has a string called "ID" which is pretty much what it sounds; the name of an instance of Conjunto.
The program have methods that applies the operations of union, intersection, etc, between the sets.
Everything was fine, but now i've a text file with sentences like:

- A={1,2,3}
- B={2,4,5}
- A intersection B
- B union A

And so on. The thing is, i don't know how many sets the text file contains, and i don't know how to name the variables after those sentences. For example, name an instance of Conjunto A, and name another instance B.

Sorry for the grammar, english is not my native language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty complicated to create varaibles dynamically, and pretty useless unless you have some already existing code that expects certain variables.

Use a `Dictionary<string, Conjunto>` to hold your instances of the class. That way you can access them by name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to try that,

Answer (score 3):

First off, If you don't target lower version than .Net 2.0 use List instead of ArrayList. If I were you I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. Use [HashSet or SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) to store the numbers and then you can use defined union and intersection.

Secondly, what is your goal? Do want to have just the output set after all operations? Do you want to read and store all actions and them process it on some event?

Comment: My goal is to execute the operations and then print them on another .txt. Anyway, i've come (thanks to your replies people) to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your program is taken from bad side. I would advice to start making new one. One of ways to name "variables" dynamicaly is by making class objects and editing their properties.

This is what I made as a starting platform:

First af all I have crated a class called set

```
class set
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<int> numbers { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have made the code to sort whole textfile into list of those classes:

```
            List<set> Sets = new List<set>();
            string textfile = "your text file";
            char[] spliter = new char[] { ',' };  //switch that , to whatever you want but this will split whole textfile into fragments of sets
            List<string> files = textfile.Split(spliter).ToList<string>();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                set set = new set();
                set.ID = i.ToString();

                char[] secondspliter = new char[] { ',' };  //switch that , to whatever you want but this will split one set into lone numbers
                List<string> data = textfile.Split(secondspliter).ToList<string>();
                foreach (string number in data)
                {
                    bool success = Int32.TryParse(number, out int outcome);
                    if (success)
                    {
                        set.numbers.Add(outcome);
                    }

                }
                i++;
                Sets.Add(set);
            }
```

Hope it helps someone.